# Expressions are not evaluated in the nested ansible variables

Tags: ansible

```
$ ls play.d/roles/debug/*
play.d/roles/debug/tasks:
main.yml

play.d/roles/debug/vars:
main.yml
```

---

```
$ cat play.d/roles/debug/tasks/main.yml 
- debug: msg="{{ name }}"
- debug: msg="{{ vars[name]['test_var'] }}"
- debug: msg="{{ vars['nested_var']['test_var'] }}"
- debug: msg="{{ test_var }}"
```

---

```
$ cat play.d/roles/debug/vars/main.yml 
test_var: "{{ 'value-1' if cpu == 'x64' else 'value-2' }}"

nested_var:
  test_var: "{{ 'value-1' if cpu == 'x64' else 'value-2' }}"
```

---

```
$ cat play.d/debug.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
    - debug
```

---

```
$ cat inv.d/inv
[all:vars]
cpu = 'x64'

[test-srv]
52.19.xxx.xxx
```

---

With this pretty straightforward setup I expect that `Ansible` should evaluate inline conditionals regardless of their position (top level or nested). However it seems, that nested variables become literal strings of the expressions:

```
# ansible-playbook -i inv.d/inv play.d/debug.yml -e name=nested_var -l test-srv

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [52.19.xxx.xxx]

TASK: [debug | debug msg="{{ name }}"] **************************************** 
ok: [52.19.xxx.xxx] => {
    "msg": "nested_var"
}

TASK: [debug | debug msg="{{ vars[name]['test_var'] }}"] ********************** 
ok: [52.19.xxx.xxx] => {
    "msg": "{{'value-1' if cpu == 'x64' else 'value-2'}}"
}

TASK: [debug | debug msg="{{ vars['nested_var']['test_var'] }}"] ************** 
ok: [52.19.xxx.xxx] => {
    "msg": "{{'value-1' if cpu == 'x64' else 'value-2'}}"
}

TASK: [debug | debug msg="{{ 'value-1' if cpu == 'x64' else 'value-2' }}"] **** 
ok: [52.19.xxx.xxx] => {
    "msg": "value-1"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
52.19.xxx.xxx               : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Who's doing it wrong, me or `Ansible`? Any ideas?

```
# ansible --version
ansible 1.9.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you try to achieve, but you exploit an undocumented way of accessing variables via `vars` hash.
And this `vars` hash is special in a way that Ansible template engine **will not** template it, but return it's value as is.
For Ansible 2.x it's described [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/template/vars.py#L85).
So in case of `{{ vars[name]['test_var'] }}` it will resolve `name->'nested_var'` first but will not then resolve `vars['nested_var']['test_var']` and return it as literal string.

If your variables are defined as host facts (inventory-host/group variables, dynamic facts set by `set_fact`), you can access `host_vars` [magic variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) like `host_vars[inventory_hostname][dynamic_name]['subelement']` to access variable dynamically.

If your variables are play/role bound, like in your case, I can suggest to use root-hash with predefined name, like:

```
known_name:
  nested_var: # this key name is known known in advance
    subelement: "{{ 'value-1' if cpu == 'x64' else 'value-2' }}"
```

Here you can access dynamic element by `known_name[dynamic_name]['subelement']`.